# Why .insert operator in map will not replace key value pair if same key exist?

Tags: c++, maps, std

```
//map key values are:
map[first] = 1, map[second]=5
map.insert(std::make_pair(second,15)); //still, map[second] =5
```

I know that `map[second] = 15`, will solve it but I wanted to know exactly why `.insert` operator will not do the same? What is difference between `.insert` and `[]` operator?

Comment: `std::map` member function [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and member operator [**at**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: It's called "insert", not ["insert_or_assign"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign).

Comment: There wouldn't make any sense for both `[]` and `.insert` to do the same thing, would it? After all, if that's the case, why have both?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027079/why-insert-from-stdmap-doesnt-want-to-update-c